# Where is the link to the Privileges page?

Tags: support

I couldn't find the link to reach the [Privileges page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/privileges). So my question is: is there no link/button that does that or I just couldn't find it?

Comment: +1,because i was also facing the same problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I always find the privileges page is:

- go to the [Help Center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help) (which is linked from the drop-down menu which is always at the top right of the screen on every page on the site)
- scroll down to the "Privileges" section and click on "[View a full list of privileges you can earn](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)"

There you'll be able to see a list of all privileges, both those you've earned and those you haven't.

Answer (score 2):

One way will take you two clicks:

- Click the Badges button on the ribbon
- On the Badges page, click the Privileges link in the window at the top-right